# React API Error (Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

im very new to API stuff but I got stuck on something.
I got this error when converting a youtube tutorial's explaination to another API that I need to use.

The error that I receive is `'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined'.`
Which points me to this line in my code:
`this.setState({person: data.results[0], loading: false });`

(The component it's in.)

`async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "https://api.floraxchange.nl/artikel?relatieid=215&Code=214325432";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({person: data.results[0], loading: false });
  }`

Comment: It looks like results from data.results is undefined. Try logging data to see what it looks like (i.e. console.log(data) after it's returned).

Comment: @DonBrody it returns this:
`(40) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ID: 268431, Code: "12 TCMIX", Naam: "Dragonmix in Terra Cotta met schotel", Potmaat: "13 cm", PotmaatNumeriek: 13, …}`

Comment: i think it should be ({person: data.result[0], loading:false });

Comment: @HastaTamangThat gives the same error but replacing '0' with 'items'
I appreciate your help either way :)

Comment: It looks like the `results` array is returned at the top level. So you can probably try `data[0]` instead of `data.results[0]`.

Comment: @DonBrody that works like a charm, thank you all a lot!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to @DonBrody, so I can close this question)

It looks like the results array is returned at the top level. So you can probably try data[0] instead of data.results[0]

Thank you all a lot <3